# Uncaught TypeError: CKEDITOR.style.addCustomHandler is not a function

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

ckeditor 4 не понятной подверсии (переписали, и удалили информацию о версии). Поставил для него плагин codesnippet, он свою очередь потребовал плагины widget и lineutils. Их поставил, там дальше ругается:

1. > Uncaught TypeError: CKEDITOR.style.addCustomHandler is not a function
2. > Uncaught TypeError: CKEDITOR.tools.objectKeys is not a function

Что не так делаю? Версия ckeditor и плагина не совпадает? В конфиг добавил

```
config.extraPlugins = 'codesnippet';
```